# asp.net mvc vs javascript build whole site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

i am building a site. There are two choices for me.

1. asp.net mvc 3.0 + ajax.
2. build whole site with ajax(javascript). Firstly, use ajax to get data with json format, and   then fill the whole page with the data. In this way, the page will be produced only via javascript.

Could anyone tell me the advantages and disadvantages of these two ways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look here http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/ I use a lot of jQuery but at the same time there is some static content

Comment: A good example of what you can achieve with asp.net MVC with added javascript is this site!
http://stackoverflow.com :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is not for building entire markup and rendering it. Don't shoot yourself in the foot.

Use ASP.Net MVC to build your site. Along side of ASP.Net MVC use jQuery/javascript to build ajax functionality.

Comment: Very useful answer. Could you please detail it more ?

Answer (score 3):

If you choose the second option, it won't work in browsers with no JavaScript support. This may not seem all that important to you, but consider: most search engines don't support JavaScript. If search engines can't get the content on your site, it won't get ranked well.